# Using XSLT to pad zeros to numbers in a string

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have an XSLT (version 1.0) to pick out a string which contains numbers and not all of them have leading zeros. The problem is that this string is now being used to sort elements alphabetically.

Ideally running the XSLT (amongst other changes) should change:

```
<atom name="EADUnitID" type="text" size="short">BODA.4.3.60</atom>
<atom name="EADUnitID" type="text" size="short">BODA.4.3.61</atom>
```

To:

```
<field name="heirarchy_sequence">BODA.04.03.60</field>
<field name="heirarchy_sequence">BODA.04.03.60</field>
```

How can I rewrite our XSLT so that it pads the numbers from this string with zeros when necessary? 
The other little hiccup is that the delimiter between the text and numbers in the string isn't always a '.' sometimes it might be a '-'.

As I'm declaring the PHP namespace, I thought I might use PHP functions to break down the string and sprinntf to format the number parts but I get the feeling this won't work...

**My XSLT looks like this:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="add">
    <add>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </add>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:copy>
        ...     
            <field name="heirarchy_sequence">
                 <xsl:value-of select="atom[@name='EADUnitID'][normalize-space()]"/>
            </field>
        ...
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**And the XML file it is changing looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml_split:root xmlns:xml_split="http://xmltwig.com/xml_split">
<doc name="record">
    <atom name="irn" type="text" size="short">6135</atom>
    <atom name="ObjectType" type="text" size="short">Archives</atom>
    <atom name="EADLevelAttribute" type="text" size="short">Item</atom>
    <atom name="EADUnitID" type="text" size="short">BODA.4.3.60</atom>
  </doc>
  <doc name="record">
    <atom name="irn" type="text" size="short">6136</atom>
    <atom name="ObjectType" type="text" size="short">Archives</atom>
    <atom name="EADLevelAttribute" type="text" size="short">Item</atom>
    <atom name="EADUnitID" type="text" size="short">BODA.4.3.61</atom>
  </doc>
  </xml_split:root>
```

**Edit 1**

Removed unnecessary `</table>` from xml example

**Edit 2 - Examples of variations**

```
<atom name="EADUnitID" type="text" size="short">gls-1-1-1</atom>
<atom name="EADUnitID" type="text" size="short">gls-1-1-2</atom>
```

Comment: couldnt you explode by the `.` and check the length of the string. If its under whats expected add however many digits its under by?

Comment: Your XML is invalid on account of the unmatched `</table>` end tag.  Is that supposed to be a real part of of your data?

Comment: It would be useful to have a proper specification of the input you have to deal with, rather than just two example inputs and a statement that variations on this can occur.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that was a typo - the records contain more rows and tuples none of which were pertinent so I tried to remove them. Must have missed that closing tag though - good spot. I've edited the question to remove the tag.

Comment: @MichaelKay - sorry, I'll add the examples of the other variations.

Comment: So, we're still trying to infer a spec from isolated examples. Would it be fair to conclude that the data is always in the form `S*N*N*N` where S is alphabetic, N is numeric, and `*` is any single punctuation character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're the using the `libxslt` processor, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="atom[@name='EADUnitID']">
    <field name="heirarchy_sequence">
        <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="str:tokenize(., '.-')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[1]" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$tokens[position() > 1]">
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="str:align(., '0000', 'right')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </field>
</xsl:template>
```

to transform:

```
<atom name="EADUnitID" type="text" size="short">BODA.4.3.60</atom>
<atom name="EADUnitID" type="text" size="short">BODA.4.3.61</atom>
<atom name="EADUnitID" type="text" size="short">gls-1-1-1</atom>
<atom name="EADUnitID" type="text" size="short">gls-1-1-2</atom>
```

into:

```
<field name="heirarchy_sequence">BODA.0004.0003.0060</field>
<field name="heirarchy_sequence">BODA.0004.0003.0061</field>
<field name="heirarchy_sequence">gls.0001.0001.0001</field>
<field name="heirarchy_sequence">gls.0001.0001.0002</field>
```

See: http://exslt.org/str/index.html

Comment: P.S. That's not how you spell "hierarchy".